# Classical JNI error in my Maven project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have some problems compiling a maven project in netbeans.

When i run it inside Netbeans, it works fine, but when i compile it, i receive 
the error

"a jni error has occurred please check your installation and try again"

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pmi</groupId>
<artifactId>PSSynchro</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>     
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>pmi.pssynchro.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If I remove this section

```
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
          <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
       </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
```

it works, but some functions, naturally, not.

Answer (score 0):

Understand - Cause why this occur, please share complete error. error may be occur from these reasons

1) Any of your file is present at the compile time but its not reachable at the execution time

2) You need to crosscheck both compile time and run time environment & class paths.

you can also try these solution.

1. Uninstall ALL Java. Including Netbeans.
2. Install JRE8 & JDK8.
3. Install NetBeans again

Worked like a charm. For some reason JDK/JRE wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks Mayank, I will try project on my installation on notebook at home instead of uninstalling/reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
To make my compiled jar working, i had to remove 4 files from it.
In META-INF folder i had to remove:
MSFTSIG.SF, MSFTSIG.RSA, BCKEY.DSA, BCKEY.SF

It looks like they are signature files. i don't know how don't include them during compiling.

Anyway I also changed dependency with

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But errore persist (except that jar is lighter and i had to remove only 2 files from META -INF).